# "row" in CSS Bootstrap is very high, can I make it of the same height as its embedded div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple website, with Bootstrap CSS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
                        
        <style>
        
                /* width */
                ::-webkit-scrollbar {
                    width: 5px;
                }

                /* Scrollbar background */
                ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
                    background: rgb(244, 244, 244);
                }

                /* Scrollbar handle */
                ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
                    background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 12);
                }

                /* Scrollbar handle on hover */
                ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
                    background: rgb(80, 20, 160);
                }
                
                
                p, ul {
                    font-family:Consolas;
                    padding:1%;
                    font-size:12px
                }
                
                footer {
                    text-align:center;
                    font-size:10px;
                }
                
                
                #scrollablediv {
                    overflow-y: scroll;
                    height:50%;
                }

                
                /* Making images black-and-white and colourful when hovered. */
                img {
                    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
                    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
                    filter: grayscale(100%);
                    transition: all .5s ease;
                }       
                img:hover {
                    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
                    -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
                    filter: grayscale(0%);
                }       
        </style>
        
    </head>

    <body style="margin:.2%; padding:3%; height: 70px">

        <header>
            <h1 style="font-family:consolas; font-size:18px">Header here!</h1>
        </header>
    
        <hr>
                
        <div class="row">
        
            <div class="col-lg-2">
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <div id="scrollablediv">
                    <h6>Title1</h6>
                    <p>
                        <b>TL;DR:</b> Some text..
                        <br><br>
                        <b>TS;WM:</b> Some text..
                    </p>

                    <h6>Title2</h6>
                    <p> Some text..
                    </p>

                    <h6>Title3</h6>
                    
                    <ul style="font-family:Consolas; font-size:12px; list-style-position: inside;">
                        <li>
                            Some text..
                        <li>
                        <li>
                            Some text..
                        <li>
                    </ul>                       
                
                    <h6>Title4</h6>
                    <p>
                        Some text..
                    </p>
            
                    <h6>Title5</h6>
                    <p>
                        Some text..
                    </p>

                    <h6>Title6</h6>
                    
                    <ul style="font-family:Consolas; font-size:12px; list-style-position: inside;">
                        <li>
                            Some text..
                        <li>
                        <li>
                            Some text..
                        <li>
                    </ul>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <footer>© 2022.</footer>
            </div>
        <div class="row">

        <script src="bootstrap-5.2.2-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When it renders on a desktop monitor, `<div class="row">` element gets really high, respectively, pushing this property to all its children elements (cols).

If you'll open this website, you'll notice, that height of the `scrollablediv` element is not that high, but its container `row` element is really high. I want to have a wrapper row of the same size as its children cols.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Hope it's work for you !!!

you need to add class `align-items-start` in main row, and also set height of scrollable div in `px` instead of `%`

```css
/* width */
                ::-webkit-scrollbar {
                    width: 5px;
                }

                /* Scrollbar background */
                ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
                    background: rgb(244, 244, 244);
                }

                /* Scrollbar handle */
                ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
                    background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 12);
                }

                /* Scrollbar handle on hover */
                ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
                    background: rgb(80, 20, 160);
                }
                
                
                p, ul {
                    font-family:Consolas;
                    padding:1%;
                    font-size:12px
                }
                
                footer {
                    text-align:center;
                    font-size:10px;
                }
                
                
                #scrollablediv {
                    overflow-y: scroll;
                    height:300px;
                }

                
                /* Making images black-and-white and colourful when hovered. */
                img {
                    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
                    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
                    filter: grayscale(100%);
                    transition: all .5s ease;
                }       
                img:hover {
                    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
                    -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
                    filter: grayscale(0%);
                }
```

```html
<body style="margin:.2%; padding:3%; height: 70px">

        <header>
            <h1 style="font-family:consolas; font-size:18px">Header here!</h1>
        </header>
    
        <hr>
                
        <div class="row align-items-start">
        
            <div class="col-lg-2">
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <div id="scrollablediv">
                    <h6>Title1</h6>
                    <p>
                        <b>TL;DR:</b> Some text..
                        <br><br>
                        <b>TS;WM:</b> Some text..
                    </p>

                    <h6>Title2</h6>
                    <p> Some text..
                    </p>

                    <h6>Title3</h6>
                    
                    <ul style="font-family:Consolas; font-size:12px; list-style-position: inside;">
                        <li>
                            Some text..
                        <li>
                        <li>
                            Some text..
                        <li>
                    </ul>                       
                
                    <h6>Title4</h6>
                    <p>
                        Some text..
                    </p>
            
                    <h6>Title5</h6>
                    <p>
                        Some text..
                    </p>

                    <h6>Title6</h6>
                    
                    <ul style="font-family:Consolas; font-size:12px; list-style-position: inside;">
                        <li>
                            Some text..
                        <li>
                        <li>
                            Some text..
                        <li>
                    </ul>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <footer>© 2022.</footer>
            </div>
        <div class="row">

        <script src="bootstrap-5.2.2-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm upvoting this; however, changing `%` to `px` kinda helps.. but I wanted percentage (instead of pixels) because of the point, that I want it to be of relative size onto different screens. Having `px` is a fixed size. Any chances to have similar behaviour with percentage/relative value? also, no difference is applied whether I have a `class="row"` or `class=""row align-items-start"`.